# Installing Garuda Linux throws errors

Tags: linux

I wanted to dual-boot Garuda Linux alongside Windows 10 on my computer.

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042
System Manufacturer Acer
System Model    Swift SF314-510G
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  0000000000000000
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde Corp. V1.10, 31-03-2021
SMBIOS Version  3.3
Embedded Controller Version 1.10
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  TGL
BaseBoard Product   Brahma_TL
BaseBoard Version   V1.10
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Off
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Kernel DMA Protection   On
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled

booting from my pendrive leads to
[garuda installation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUdNS.jpg)

I click on "Boot with open source drivers" and it leads to this screen displaying a bunch of errors. It remains stuck and doesn't proceed
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL7JA.jpg)

I have no prior experience of installing any of the Linux distros.

Comment: For a beginner I'd recommend starting with something more user friendly than Arch derivatives. Ubuntu is probably your best bet with its large community.

Comment: @gronostaj Ubuntu was my first choice, again ran into errors there [link](https://imgur.com/FXLkBbG)